# switching between different inputViews for the same textfields

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app, I have a textfield that takes its input from a picker view. However, the user could not find his preferred option so I added above the textfield a small button resembling a keyboard. Once the button is pressed the textfield's picker view should disappear and the keyboard should appear instead so that the user enter his preferred data. So how can I do that? I tried resigning it as first responder and then making it become the first responder hoping the picker could be released as the input view but it didn't work. Adding a textfield as an accessory input view will not look right (having two textfield the user should update the first one instead).

Comment: What about using the reloadInputViews method on UIResponder which UITextField inherits from?

Comment: Not getting your question. Can you show your code? What have you tried?

Comment: You can use a toggle condition on button click and on clicking on button you can make something done or edit...and in textFiledBeginEditing change as per condition toggling